# multiple things in If statement js

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

Is there a way to set multiple things in an If statement?  For example in the below code, I want to set both status and icon variables if something is true or false.  This code is not working and I'm suspecting it's because && doesn't compute, but couldn't find a solution.  Any suggestions?

```
var status;
var icon;
if(x.life > 0) {
    status = "Yes" && icon == "fa-check-circle-o"
} else {
    status = "No" && icon == " fa-times-circle-o"
}
```

Comment: Do you want to check the values or set the values ?

Comment: I want to set the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to set multiple things in an If statement? For example
>   in the below code, I want to set both status and icon variables if
>   something is true or false.

Sure, it is possible, However, it's not working currently because you're not correctly assigning the values. use a single ( `=` ) for assignment  and double ( `==` ) for comparison (will return `boolean`).

*Try this:*

```
var status;
var icon;
if(x.life > 0) {
    status = "Yes";
    icon = "fa-check-circle-o";
} else {
    status = "No";
    icon = " fa-times-circle-o";
}
```

Comment: @Dave sure, would really appreciate it if you mark the answer as accepted if it has helped.

Comment: haha will do, it won't let me mark correct for another 5 min.

Comment: @Dave sure, no problem :).

Answer (score 1):

Make two separate statement instead of using `&&` and use `=` instead of `==` when assigning value to variable.

```
var status;
var icon;
if(x.life > 0) {
   status = "Yes"; 
   icon = "fa-check-circle-o"
} else {
   status = "No";
   icon = " fa-times-circle-o";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use && here which will make your statement a condition.
And == will check for equality not compare items

```
var status;
var icon;
if(x.life > 0) {
    status = "Yes";
    icon = "fa-check-circle-o";
} else {
    status = "No";
    icon = " fa-times-circle-o";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to separate them with semicolon or `enter`.

```
   var status;
   var icon;
   if(x.life > 0) {
       status = "Yes";
       icon == "fa-check-circle-o";
   } else {
       status = "No";  
       icon == " fa-times-circle-o";
   }
```

Note that `&&` is commonly used for boolean arguments;
example:

```
   if(x.life > 0 && y.life > 0) {
       status = "Yes";
       icon == "fa-check-circle-o";
   }
```

Comment: *"Note that && is only used for boolean arguments"* - No it's not. You can use it with any types.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set `status` based on the value of `icon` (since you have == in the original code):

```
var status;
var icon;
if (x.life > 0) {
    if (icon == "fa-check-circle-o") {
        status = "Yes";
    }
} else {
    if (icon == "fa-times-circle-o") {
        status = "No";
    }
}
```